# TableView not reloading data and sometimes reload data when tried with breakpoints

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, urlsession

This is some API Fetch Code and it successfully returns the data, but `reloadData()` gets called only when I set breakpoints. If I remove the breakpoints, it simply renders out the UIView under my table view in the view debugger, instead of my custom cells. (Accomodation Cell)

```
API.shared.fetchAccomodations(completion: { (accResponse, error) in
    if let err = error {
        print("Failed to fetch accommodation information ::" , err.localizedDescription)
    }
    if let response = accResponse {
        self.accomodationsData = response
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(self.accomodationsData.count, self.accomodationsData)
            self.tableView.reloadData()                
        }            
    }        
}, tokenURL: accomodationsURL)
```

I am using two tableviews. This is tableview methods where I'm using if else for both tableviews.

```
if tableView == courseInfoTableView {
    return numberOfCourses
}
else {
    return accomodationsData.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView ==  courseInfoTableView {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "courseCell", for: indexPath) as? CourseInfoCell {
            cell.durationLabel.text = "General English"
            cell.durationLbl.text = "1-4 Weeks"
            cell.priceLbl.text = "1500 SAR" 
        } else if tableView == self.tableView {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AccomodationCell", for: indexPath) as? AccomodationCell {
                cell.titleLabel.text = AccomodationsData[indexPath.row].residenceName
                cell.subtitleLabel.text = AccomodationsData[indexPath.row].residenceType            
                cell.bedImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DoubleBed")
                return cell
            }
        }                    
    }                
    return UITableViewCell()                
}
```

On start, I'm setting both tableviews height constraints programmatically because they are in a scroll view.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    tableViewHeight.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    InfoTVHeight.constant = courseInfoTableView.contentSize.height                
}
```

Comment: Is it a typo that you are referring to `AccomodationsData` (capital A) in `cellForRowAt`?  Also, don't use conditional downcasting in `cellForRow`, it can hide bugs. Use a forced downcast and crash if there is a misconfiguration, find the bug and fix it.

Comment: You say in your post that you have two UITableViews but when you attempt to reload, you are only calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` on one view. Is that intended?

Comment: Also note that while you are creating the `courseCell` you do not have a return statement, so the function will return `UITableViewCell()` which is probably not what you want. You can fix this by taking the approach explained by @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11 I mistyped here but I dont doing this type in the code so thats not the issue.
conditional downcasting you mean? I should force downcast to AccomodationCell?

Comment: @alain.s I'm reloading data for the tableview whose datasource is changed.Accomodations tableview name is tableview and I'm reloading its data.

Comment: @alain.s Again It's a type here as I'm returning the cell in the code otherwise that would cause me an error.

Comment: @AhsanMughal So after `cell.priceLbl.text = "1500 SAR"` in your code, you have a statement `return cell` or not? If you do, please edit the question to match your code exactly. If not, you have a bug as you actually return a new UITableViewCell at the end of the method instead of the one you've created.